# Merge images with PHP

Tags: php

I have written a code for merge two images.

My code is:

```
$rnd = rand("99000", "99999");

$dst_path = "/home/maxioutl/public_html/images/urunler/";
$dst_file_name = "tresim-{$rnd}.jpg";
$dst_file = $dst_path.$dst_file_name;

$dst = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 375);
imagefill($dst, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($dst, 255, 255, 255));

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://www.goldstore.com.tr/upload/product/raw/3.72925.0332.JPG");

imagecopymerge($dst, $src, 40, 60, 0, 0, 250, 375, 100);

imagejpeg($dst, $dst_file, 90);
```

Result:

[image: black bg]
Black background. Where is it?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: i want white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote superimposes the images. It does not remove the white pixels from the image with the watch.

They are basically overlapped.

You should cycle through both image dimensions and replace each *white pixel with a black pixel or a transparent pixel.

*white pixel may not necessarily mean rgb(255,255,255) you can choose to treat all pixels with rgb(>235,>235,>235) as being "white".

Answer (score 1):

It's the `imagecopymerge($dst, $src, 40, 60, 0, 0, 250, 375, 100);` statement that's doing it.

You're passing it the dimensions `250x375`, which isn't the watch's actual dimensions. Therefore the merge bounding box continues on and it uses black. You can see this easily if you comment it out because you'll get your white square from the fill like you were expecting.

you need to get the exact dimensions of your watch graphic (i.e. through `getimagesize`) and pass those to imagecopymerge so it cuts it exactly when it merges.

```
$arrSize = getimagesize($originalFile);
imagecopymerge($dst, $src, 40, 60, 0, 0, $arrSize[0], $arrSize[1], 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `imagecreatetruecolor` creates completely black image
Taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) :

> imagecreatetruecolor() returns an image identifier representing a
>   black image of the specified size.